# How to define a Jenkins build parameter to refer the ${BUILD_NUMBER} env variable

Tags: jenkins

is it possible to refer the Jenkins ${BUILD_NUMBER} variable in the default value of a Jenkins String parameter? I can't manage to do that.

Comment: You can't. What exactly you are trying to achieve, Could you state your problem?

Comment: I am trying to have the same job being triggered either manually or by another job. When it is run manually, the parameter should be entered by the user, but when it is triggered by the other build, that parameter should get the default value, which is a string like 0.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}. The job is building a software and the parameter is the build version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) to set the custom names to build.

To achieve your requirement, use [Pre-Scm-Buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) which executes as soon as the build starts.

Here you can use [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to add conditions based on build trigger cause, if manual cause you can set what ever format build name you want using [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) and similarly for other conditions.

Comment: Thanks, Suresh, I will give it a try. But can I then refer the custom build name? How? Because I have a few (post) build steps that need this value.

Comment: You can create a environment variable what ever format you are looking and then you can refer this variable through out the build process and same variable you can pass to Build Name Setter build step. To create environment variable in run-time use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)